# Android ending activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I go through few activities and when I want to go back to main window I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP but if I press back button then I would go back to other activities that I went through.

Briefly speaking I want to go to main activity and after presing back button it wouldn't go to other activities.

**EDITED**
This clossing all activities is used to complete logoff process in another words it shouldn't user let to go back. I can't use BackPressed(), because I am using putExtra and getExtra. Maybe someone could write small sample. Because I don't understand flag system.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` on Activities you don't want saved on the stack.  When the user presses `back` he/she will go to the last activity that didn't have that flag set.

Comment: could you specify in which place to put this flag?

Comment: In the Intent you use for `startActivity()`.  [Developers Guide Activity Fundamentals.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Comment: Alternatively, you can set "noHistory" to true as an Activity attribute in your manifest.  You only really want to do this when you're 100% sure your activity should not be reentered when the user presses back (though functionally it doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 0):

You can override [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in your activity and start your desired one with the flags:
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`